# Templatize Go Code that can be used to generate new code

Tags: go, templates

I have multiple services which are using `grpc` to expose endpoints. The process to create a new endpoint is pretty generic

1. Create the definition of new endpoint in `api.proto`
2. Update `grpc.go` file to connect `encoders`/`decoders`/`servicelayer` using `go-kit` library
3. Update `ServiceInterface` to expose new method from service layer
4. Write code in `ServiceImplementation` for new method.

The steps number 2 & 3 are pretty generic. The code in `grpc.go` is literally just creating a new field to a `apiendpoitns` struct and then creating a make function for it.

I am trying to automate step 2 & 3. What I want to ask that is there any *go way* to templatize `go` code that can be used to create new `*.go` code? I foresee that i may have to create dynamic number of methods from that template file. any pointers?

Comment: Use the [text/template](https://godoc.org/text/template) package for templating and the [go/format](https://godoc.org/go/format#Source) package to format the result.

Comment: but isn't that package for `html` type of templating?

Comment: The text/template package is **not** recommended for html templating.